# KendoUI Sortable like JQueryUI

Tags: jquery-ui, kendo-ui

Looking for an example of using KendoUI like the JQueryUI sortable method. Can't seem to find anything like this. What a shame if you can't do this in KendoUI.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have the same look & feel that other KendoUI widgets you might try to implement it using TreeView:

If this are the elements that are sortable:

```
var dataSource = [
    { id:1, text:"Element 1" },
    { id:2, text:"Element 2" },
    { id:3, text:"Element 3" },
    { id:4, text:"Element 4" },
    { id:5, text:"Element 5" },
    { id:6, text:"Element 6" }
];
```

then you might use the following code:

```
$("#sortable").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource :dataSource,
    template   :"<div class='ob-item'> #= item.text # </div>",
    dragAndDrop:true,
    drag       :function (e) {
        var dst = $($(e.dropTarget).closest(".k-item")[0]).data("uid");
        var src = $(e.sourceNode).data("uid");
        if ($(e.dropTarget).hasClass("ob-item") && dst != src) {
            e.setStatusClass("k-insert-top");
        } else {
            e.setStatusClass("k-denied");
        }
    },
    drop       :function (e) {
        if ($(e.sourceNode).data("uid") !== $(e.destinationNode).data("uid")) {
            $(e.sourceNode).insertBefore(e.destinationNode);
        }
        e.setValid(false);
    }
});
```

that renders a sortable list.

NOTES:

`ob-item` is the styling that you want for each sortable item. For example:

```
.ob-item {
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    border: 1px solid #a99f9a;
    color: #2e2e2e;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

If you allow nesting then you should replace `insertBefore` by `append`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do that in KendoUi.  I agree, their documentation could be a little more clear, but check out under treeview drag & drop:

http://demos.kendoui.com/web/treeview/dragdrop.html

Comment: is there a way to persist this sorting server side?

Comment: Kendoui is a client side library. Yes you could, but it would be with your server side language.  I don't see why you would have to though. It just puts more computations on the server.

Comment: sorry, the sort order (set by the stacking/ordering on the client) is custom by user and needed for application (in my case need)

Comment: Regarding persisting the list, I don't see why that's an unreasonable question.  What good is a sortable list if it doesn't persist?  If you come back to the list and it's back in the default order, its useless.

Answer (score 2):

For those who find this question. Now Kendo UI has Sortable element: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/sortable/index.html

Answer (score 1):

You can build a custom jQuery UI js file with the custom builder: http://jqueryui.com/download

Just get the reference to include the ui core and the sortable function you require, the file size will be minimal and you will get the functionality you are looking for.

Since Kendo UI works with jQuery, the added weight of jQuery UI is minimal.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
  var template = kendo.template("<ul id='sortable-basic'><li class='sortable'>Papercut <span>3:04</span></li><li class='sortable'>One Step Closer <span>2:35</span></li><li class='sortable'>With You <span>3:23</span></li><li class='sortable'>Points of Authority <span>3:20</span></li><li class='sortable'>Crawling <span>3:29</span></li><li class='sortable'>Runaway <span>3:03</span></li><li class='sortable'>By Myself <span>3:09</span></li></ul>");

$("#divSolution").html(template); //display the result
$("#sortable-basic").kendoSortable();
```